# PHP selecting from a MYSql view Returns Nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, view, resultset

This is odd and I just can't seem to find what is wrong.
Here is a simple example:

In my PHP code, I can select from a table and have results returned.
But, If I change my SQL statement to select from a view, no results are returned.

This Code Returns results:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$sql_stmt_bind = "Select fk_member_id as ID FROM member_role LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $link->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql_stmt_bind);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($mem_id);
$stmt->fetch();

echo '<br>';
echo 'rows: ' . $stmt->num_rows;
echo '<br>';
//echo 'lastname: ' . $lastname;
echo 'ID: ' . $mem_id;
echo '<br>';
```

The Results:

```
rows: 1
ID: 1
```

This Code Returns unexpected results:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$sql_stmt_bind = "Select fk_member_id as ID FROM vw_test LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $link->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql_stmt_bind);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($mem_id);
$stmt->fetch();

echo '<br>';
echo 'rows: ' . $stmt->num_rows;
echo '<br>';
//echo 'lastname: ' . $lastname;
echo 'ID: ' . $mem_id;
echo '<br>';
```

The Results:

```
rows: 0
ID: 0
```

This is the Create statement for the View:

```
Create or replace View vw_test
 as
Select fk_member_id FROM member_role 
;
```

So I'm at a total loss.
I've been running the same code for the past 4 or 5 years with no issues.
(This is for a community sports association and runs for only a few months of the year.)
I was double checking the code before I turned on the web pages again...and now all of my code accessing views no longer works.

Please help! thanks.

**UPDATE**

I'm now using this code segment:

```
    $stmt = $link->stmt_init();
    $pre = $stmt->prepare($sql_stmt_bind);
    if ( false===$pre ) {
      die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    $exe = $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$exe ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    $stmt->store_result();

    $bind_r = $stmt->bind_result($mem_id);
    if ( false===$bind_r ) {
      die('bind_result() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    $stmt->fetch();
```

The error I now receive is:

```
execute() failed: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `Select fk_member_id as ID FROM vw_test LIMIT 1` chk in phpmyadmin

Comment: @devpro - Yes that works fine. There are no issues whatsoever with views in phpmyadmin. I can't think of anything simpler than this query.

Comment: Both r in same file?

Comment: @devpro - I'm sorry, i don't know what you mean. The table and view are in the same database yes. The view is just the same select statement that the working code uses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your code to know where the problem is.

Try this:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    $sql_stmt_bind = "Select fk_member_id as ID FROM vw_test LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $link->stmt_init();
    $pre = $stmt->prepare($sql_stmt_bind);

if ( false===$pre ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

  $exe =  $stmt->execute();

if ( false===$exe ) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

    $stmt->store_result();
    $bind_r = $stmt->bind_result($mem_id);

if ( false===$bind_r ) {
  die('bind_result() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo '<br>';
    echo 'rows: ' . $stmt->num_rows;
    echo '<br>';
    //echo 'lastname: ' . $lastname;
    echo 'ID: ' . $mem_id;
    echo '<br>';
```

**EDIT**

Work around for the problem(failed: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared)
- using the PDO adapter instead of Mysql adapter
- Add this Attribute to your connection string `$link->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`

Comment: I had tried this before, but maybe i coded it incorrectly. Anyway, i tried your suggestion and received this error returned: execute() failed: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Comment: What value do you have in table_definition_cache in 'my.cnf' ?

Comment: This is on a hosted web service. I don't have access to that, that i know of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I received this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::setAttribute(). Perhaps I need to switch to using PDO instead of mysqli ?

Comment: Post your Connection String please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106119/discussion-between-iamtheoracle-and-basti).